# Open 80 port Ubuntu Xenial 16.04

Tags: 16.04, server

I go via PuTTY:
`sudo ufw status`

[image: image_1],

but Nmap scan:

```
PORT    STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp  open     ssh
135/tcp filtered msrpc
139/tcp filtered netbios-ssn
445/tcp filtered microsoft-ds
```

`sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 80`:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1806/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1806/sshd
udp6       0      0 /mac adress here/       :::*                                1847/ntpd
```

How'd I open port 80 actually?

Comment: Do you actually have a web server listening on port 80?

Comment: @steeldriver I'd go `listen my_ip:80` in Nmap?

Comment: `netstat -nao | grep 80` returns `off (0.00/0/0)`

Comment: @Tarasovych what about `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :80`

Comment: @bistoco nothing, but `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 80` returns `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1806/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1806/sshd
udp6       0      0 /mac adress here - hidden by me/ :::*                                1847/ntpd
` sorry, I dont know about server confidence yet, so I hide `mac`

Comment: So it seems you have a firewall rule to open port 80, but you don't have any process listening on it. Did you actually installed nginx, apache or some other webserver?. We assume webserver because 80 is default port for http connections.

Comment: @bistoco awww (facepalm), no, I've not installed nginx neither apache. I'm going to do this now.

Comment: @Tarasovych, after installing it, run `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :80` and you will see the port being used by nginx, and will also get a responde in the browser when reaching the ip.

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: @bistoco: Could you please convert your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems you have a firewall rule to open port 80, but you don't have any process listening on it. Did you actually installed nginx, apache or some other webserver?. We assume webserver because 80 is default port for http connections.

After installing it, run

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :80
```

and you will see the port being used by nginx, and will also get a responde in the browser when reaching the ip.